# Am I supposed to lose everything else in my life when I lose my phone number?

Tags: security, accounts

Sorry, this isn't a coding or design problem, but it is a user-experience issue, and I'm looking for some kind of a discussion about it, and this is the best place I can come up with to discuss.

I have recently lost access to my second Yahoo account for the second time now, because I don't have my old phone number anymore. And I came very close to losing my Gmail account for a very similar reason. The mistake I feel they both did, was that they assumed how (and where) I'm going to use my accounts. But I move countries sometimes, I change my phone sometimes, I change my phone number sometimes. And every time there is drama with the online services, because signing in from a different country is "suspicious" to them.

In the case of Gmail, the only thing that saved me was that it happened to remember my phone on the Gmail app on my Android, which is a phone that I stopped using, and was already considering resetting it to let my brother use it. And if I had, I have no idea if I'd ever gain access to my Gmail account again. I tried to turn off every security option that I could find, after my email clients, like Thunderbird, always get "prevented" because they're "suspicious". Every time I sign in from a browser at work, where I use Private browsing because I don't want my details remembered, I always get a new email to the same Gmail account, and my backup email, that somebody has "suspiciously" signed in. I wrote to them (3 times) on the "feedback" link that they provide in that email to complain; no change, no response.

How was that even suspicious btw? Maybe just the first time. But afterwards, it was the same country, and it was the same computer, and it was even the same IP address because we have a static IP at work...

In the case of Yahoo, I went through all the steps of confirming it's me, they even ask me to fill in the blanks of my (now old) phone number, and I get all excited because I feel like that's gonna resolve identifying me correctly, then they ask if I can receive SMS to that number, I click no, and the next step says plain and simple "We can't help you". And that's it, that's all they had for me. Luckily for me Yahoo wasn't my primary email address.

How am I supposed to live with these security measures? I get what they're trying to do, and that's nice, but how does this all apply to my lifestyle, am I supposed to be deprived from using emailing in general because I don't stick to a single address of residence? Or was there some fundamental shift in human culture, that I've missed obviously, that says we now do have to stick to the same phone numbers because it became a way to identify us?

As a user, and because this is a user-experience issue (I think), I feel like there should be a huge option somewhere at the beginning of opening your account, that asks you what level of security you would like.

And yes, I do know that I can change my phone number if I move to another country, but first of all, there is a time frame in which I don't have one. An old phone number from my previous country is now too expensive to maintain or I had to return it to my previous employer, and I didn't get a new one in my new country yet. Second of all, there are too many services to update. If it was just Gmail, fine, I could live with that and I'd probably remember. But not to mention how paranoid Steam is, they don't even care about what's suspicious, they just send a code to my email for confirmation any time I log in from anywhere. And third of all, if I actually lose my phone, then why does that have to mean I don't get to use anything else anymore? Now I don't get to log into Gmail, and I can't get confirmation from other services (like Steam), which means I don't have anything now...

And I'm not writing this because I'm frustrated and I want to get my anger out, I'm writing because

1. I want genuine ideas as a user
2. I want genuine ideas for how web services could they maintain a secure service without intruding on a pleasant user-experience this much?

If this really is too much off-topic, feel free to delete it, but please recommend a better place where I could discuss this with professionals, and find a better way to just keep using my accounts...

Comment: Welcome to UX. stackexchange. It's an interesting issue but seems to be outside the scope of the forum.

Comment: @Mayo Thanks. As I said, I wasn't really sure and it's fine if the community disagrees, but can you recommend a better place to discuss this? I am interested in both the user point of view, and the service developers' point of view.

Comment: From a user point of view it's an argument against (some implementations of) 2 factor authentication. Perhaps switching that off or removing account recovery phone numbers for the duration of the move would help. I'm rather protective of my mobile number and don't give it to any service that *I* don't accept has need.

Comment: @ImNotMike Sorry I cannot provide a better place to ask either, but I can provide a reason why not here. Your first sentence says " it is a user-experience issue, and I'm looking for some kind of a discussion about it" but the "how to ask" section of SE sites starts with "We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed." So I don't think youre going to find a suitable SE forum for this question. Best of luck though.

Comment: @Mayo off topic - asleep at the wheel? :) http://ux.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/36314

Answer (score 0):

These are free services that use the phone number as an identifier because they are always under attack, and because most people keep the same phone number for years. The free email providers come with compromises and bad UX. That is a fact of life.

The fact that you have multiple email accounts and enough phone numbers that you can’t keep track of them and you travel a lot means you are an edge case in the eyes of free email providers. Basically, they are not interested in your problems. The solution for you is a paid email service, which comes with much better UX, easy multiple accounts, better customer service.

There are services for $10 per month or $10 per year. You can sometimes get a Web server included in that. And you can use your own domain name in many cases.

Examples:

[Zoho Mail](https://www.zoho.com/mail/)

[Rackspace $2/month email hosting](https://www.rackspace.com/email-hosting/webmail?gclid=CjwKEAiAgKu2BRDu1OGw3-KXokwSJAB_Yy2Qk0bHh4O8WZRPnqOkgh9BcJGn19HrxjVvJmWbiQMrUBoC0brw_wcB&cm_mmc=Cloud_Office-_-PPC-_-Google-_-e_business%20email&adgrpID=17678462416&kwdId=24706583&ef_id=VscwtwAAAfWBv5ux:20160222092633:s)

Answer (score 0):

Security measures will pretty much by definition be the antithesis of good UX.

Having said that this area has been vastly improved by providers. They now support  a number of recovery mechanisms because of edge cases similar to yours.

See Google's ["Sign in using backup codes"](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1187538)

One workaround is to have VoIP based telephone contact. The number can always stay the same, but be picked up anywhere in the world. I actually used this once when on holiday and my recovery codes were in the safe at home.

Comment: I don’t agree that security is the _antithesis_ of good UX. In many scenarios, security is _vital_ to the user’s experience—for example, who would use PayPal if they didn’t feel secure using their service?

Comment: yes, true, but "the additional non-goal activities that you will need to do to ensure that much needed security ..." wasn't pithy enough.